# two variables quadratic inequalities solution

Tags: inequality, quadratics, hyperbolic-functions, functional-inequalities

Suppose there are $n$ quadratic inequalities, the form is $A_i x^2 + B_i y^2 + C_i xy + D_i x + E_i y + F_i \leq 0$, $(\forall i \in [1,n])$, where $x,y$ are two variables and $(A_i, B_i, C_i, D_i, E_i, F_i)$ are constant numbers, and all the range is $[-\infty,+\infty]$. So is there a simple way to find the solutions of these quadratic inequalities?

Comment: The set of solutions will very exceptionally be a finite set of solutions, Either it will be a whole area or the empty set.  For example $x^2+y^2-1<0$ and $(x-1)^2+y^2-1<0$ (intersection area of two unit-radii disks centered in $(0,0)$ and (1,0)$ resp.) is a lens-shaped area.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually, the inequalities satisfy a hyperbola kind of curves, such like $\frac{(x-p)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(y-q)^2}{b^2} = 1$, but the foci of the hyperbolas may not exactly on the axis. In this situation, does it still same that there is a finite set of solutions, and how to judge whether the inequalities have a solution or not?

Comment: You have written "=1" ; You surely meant $<1". You have to draw the curves to have an idea of the solutions, but my answer will be the same for a family of hyperbolic constraints: unless it is an exceptional case, the solution is likely to be either a whole area of the plane or the empty set.

Comment: Yes, you are right, they are $\leq 1$. The problem is that $n$ will be very large, so it seems not possible to draw all the curves and find the overlap area. I have no idea how to reduce the computation or can I judge the answer only by the coefficient matrix, that kind of thing. Can you give me a hint or clue where to find the solution of this problem? I really appreciate it.

Comment: You should give an idea of how the $p$s and $q$s are defined. Do you agree that the solution set will be an intersection of sets. An intersection of a very large number of sets can generate almost any set...

Comment: Actually, there are a lot of 2D points, and I choose one point $z^*=(x^*,y^*)$ as an anchor, then for each other point $z_i=(x_i,y_i)$, I draw a hyperbola given $(x^*,y^*)$ and $(x_i,y_i)$ as two foci of that hyperbola, the hyperbola's center is center of $z_i, z^*$. Then for this hyperbola, there isan area holds for an inequality $|dis(z,z*)|-|dis(z,z_i)| \leq C_i$. Basically, the distribution of these 2D points are not known currently, so the $p$s and $q$s can not given. The goal is to find whether there is an overlap area for all these inequalities. not sure if I make the problem clear ...

Comment: 1) Do you mean that **one** of the foci is common to **all** hyperbolas ? 2) My impression is that, in the general case, if there are solutions they are to be found very far away from the $x$ axis.

Comment: 1) Yes, one of the foci is common, the other foci of a hyperbola is the corresponding 2D point. 2) Yeah, maybe, but how to judge whether a solution exists is a hard problem for me...

Comment: If I summarize your problem: the common focus can be (up to a translation) considered as being the origin (0,0), the other foci can be any point $(x_k,y_k)$ of the plane. I see a kind of solution by employing inversion (I don't know if you know this transformation, that, for example exists under the very good geometry software Geogebra). It could transform your problem of intersection of insides of hyperbolas int inside of circles. May be I could try to give you a hint by drawing a sketch and posting it to you as a (beginning of) anwer, because ellipses are more easily tackled.

Comment: The summarization is right. I will try that software, and that would be great if you can help drawing a sketch. Thank you so much.

Comment: I am sorry about that I misread your last comment, I am trying to draw it by myself. And I really appreciate your time and suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: I have improved my first draft. Say me if you understand all what I have written. I will read it tomorrow evening.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the picture below (done using Geogebra with the "invert into a circle" tool). You see a branch of a hyperbola having $O(0,0)$ as one of its foci. Points $C,D,...Z$ are taken on it. The inverse of these points on this hyperbolic branch are points $C',D',... Z'$. How are these points obtained ? By the following transformation rule ; let us call $M$ the generic point on the hyperbola; the rule(s) for obtaining its image $M'$ by the given inversion is :

$R_1$ : $M'$ is aligned with $O$ and $M.$

$R_2$ : The product of distances $OM.OM'=1$.

These two rules can be summarized into a single one :

$\tag{1}\vec{OM'}=\frac{\vec{OM}}{\|\vec{OM} \|^2}$

A kind of miracle occurs : points $M'$ are all situated on an arc of **ellipse**, called the inverse of the hyperbolic arc. Of course, this is not a "miracle", it can be proved in a rather simple way. See remark below.

Morevover, the inverse of the other hyperbolic branch is "inverted" into the remaining arc $C'Z'$ of the ellipse.

Besides, interior points of the hyperbola are "mapped onto" interior points of the corresponding ellipse.

Thus your problem is reduced to the intersection of interior of ellipses which is simpler because it is **bounded objects**. If your application can be "pixel-based", it should be not too much time consuming to test whether there are still pixels into the increasingly shrinking region...

Remark: the ellipse can be given an analytical expression knowing the analytical expression of the hyperbola. Here is how. Using rules $R_1$ and $R_2$ above, if the image of $M(x,y)$ is $M'(X,Y)$, the reverse is true ( $M'(X,Y)$ has $M(x,y)$ for its image) with (refer to  $(1)$ above):

$$\tag{2}(a) \ \cases{X=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\\Y=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}} \ \ \iff \ \ (b) \ \cases{x=\frac{X}{X^2+Y^2}\\y=\frac{Y}{X^2+Y^2}}$$

It suffices then to plug formulas $(2)(b)$ into the equation of the hyperbola in order to get the equation of a conic section, which should always be an ellipse in this case (it has to be checked, but I will stop here because it is 1:30 CET in the night).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Although I have not understand the relationship between original inequality and the inverted equation, you give me an inspiration for my problem. I will state my thought as the second answer, and I hope you can help me to check whether it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the question is actually to find a solution area for inequalities $|xp^*|-|xp_i| \leq C_i$, $(\forall i \in [1,n])$, where we can set $p^*$ as the origin, and $p_i (\forall i \in [1,n])$ are points in 2-dimensional plane, and $|\cdot|$ is the Elucidean distance of two points. Actually we already know that there is a solution (sorry about that I overlook this important information in the above question), but the solution point is not know. Thus for each inequality, $C_i \geq -|p^*p_i|$ holds. The reason is that if there is one $C_i < -|p^*p_i|$, we cannot find a point satisfy the inequality (due to the triangle inequality the difference of any two edges is larger than or equal to the third edge). The goal is to find whether there is only one solution or a set of solutions.

From the above discussion, we have that $C_i \geq -|p^* p_i|, (\forall i \in [i,n])$. We classify this condition in 3 situations: $[-|p^*p_i|,0)$, $[0,|p^*p_i|]$, and $(|p^*p_i|,+\infty)$. We first show when $C_i \in (|p^*p_i|,+\infty)$, the inequality $|xp^*|-|xp_i| \leq C_i$ will always satisfied (also due to triangle inequality). Then we can discuss the other two situations. When $C_i \in [0,|p^*p_i|]$, we can transform the inequality to the property of hyperbola, where we set the length of foci $\frac{|p^*p_i|}{2}$, where $p^*,p_i$ are two foci points, and the other parameter (denote $a$ in most cases) of as $\frac{C_i}{2}$. Then the solution area will be the side oriented to $p^*$ of the curve (there are 2 curves of hyperbola) that far from $p^*$ (this can be easily see by drawing a hyperbola). Similarly, when $C_i \in [-|p^*p_i|,0)$, the solution area will also be the side oriented to $p^*$, but the curve close to $p^*$.

(The below part is my intuition...) Since the solution area of each inequality is a continuous area, so the final solution area will also be one continuous area (either closed or open). And we can know that if $p_i (\forall i \in [1,n])$ distributed all over the plane in every direction (it's like to rotate a hyperbola in 360 degree with different shapes), the final solution area will be a colsed area enclosing $p^*$. In the extremely case, when all the $C_i = -|p^*p_i|$, the answer is exactly $p^*$. So if the already known solution is not $p^*$ (say $s^*$), then the solution set will be an continuous area that covered the $s^*$ and $p^*$. (Now I am not sure whether it is right and how to formalized proved this... I will appreciate it if you can help me to formalize this or give some suggestions that I should be carefully aware of. Thanks.)